# Find of Maximum of Date using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need SQL Query to find out max of done date by Type .If one the Done Date is null for particular Type then all rows will be null otherwise max of done date

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by type) = count(done_date) over (partition by type)
             then max(done_date) over (partition by type)
        end) as last_date
from t;
```

The first condition is checking if there are any `NULL` values in `done_date`.

Comment: Above query is not working without filters in where condition

Comment: @zzstar . . . I don't understand your second comment.  There are no filters, either in the question nor in this answer.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

Another window-function approach is `last_value` across all values for the partition, ordered by `done_date`, with nulls last - so a null will take precedence over any non-null value:

```
select no, done_date, type,
  last_value(done_date)
    over (
      partition by type
      order by done_date nulls last
      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
    ) as last_date
from your_table;
```

| NO | DONE_DATE | TYPE | LAST_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 02-JUL-21 | SAB1 | *null* |
| 1 | 03-JUL-21 | SAB1 | *null* |
| 1 | *null* | SAB1 | *null* |
| 2 | 06-JUL-21 | SAB2 | 07-JUL-21 |
| 2 | 07-JUL-21 | SAB2 | 07-JUL-21 |
| 2 | 09-JUL-21 | SAB3 | *null* |
| 2 | *null* | SAB3 | *null* |

Or you could use `first_value` and reverse the order, but that seems less intuitive.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f20c7d986ddbcf3dd20ceb5c42b0db4)

Comment: This query is working with filters only in where clause..Without where clause its not working

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Wrong results, or an error? And what kind of filters, and why are they there or being removed? Possibly you need a case expression inside the `last_value()` clause but it's impossible to tell. Maybe ask a new question showing your data (as text, not an image), your queries, and what the problem is.